# Redefinition of 'Class' as different kind of symbol - OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, parse-platform

I have two classes:
User and Picture:

```
    #import <ParseOSX/ParseOSX.h>

@class User;

@interface Picture : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) User *owner;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile * picFile;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@end
```

and

```
    #import <ParseOSX/ParseOSX.h>

@class Picture;

@interface User : PFObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * facebookId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * fullname;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFGeoPoint * location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Picture * avatar;

@end
```

But the Xcode said:

Redefinition of 'Picture' as different kind of symbol.

P/S : These classes work well on the iOS project :(.

Comment: Is `owner` in `Picture` the same `User` which has this `Picture` as `avatar`? If yes, then, regardless of other problems, you have retain cycle.

Comment: Use a 3 Character Prefix for you class names.  It's Objective-C's way of "namespacing" - Swift fixes this.

Comment: Why don't you import one class into another's h-file? Then one of the @class directive would be unneccessary.

Comment: Hm, In order to compile Picture class, compiler needs Owner class, and in order to compile Owner it needs Picture. It sounds bad. Maybe redefine your architecture and make User class without picture, then make for example UserWithPicture that inherits from User, and Picture that owns User. Think that would certainly resolve any issues you might have with cross including.

Comment: @Kreiri, Thank you for your reply, this problem was solved, but that mean the Xcode showed wrong warning message for this case ?